# Как сделать прозрачный фон у annotate matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня есть график, при помощи аннотации я добавляю текст, но белый прямоугольник скрывает часть графика , как сделать его прозрачным?

Comment: Приведите ваш код, чтобы проще было воспроизвести ситуацию и поэкспериментировать.

Comment: @CrazyElf увы не могу( я думал может есть параметр какой нибудь, там используется annotate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У объекта `Text` есть `bounding_box`. Вам нужно изменить свойства этого объекта вызовом метода [`Text.set_bbox`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text.set_bbox):

```
txt = plt.text(x, y, 'Min = 0.5')
txt.set_bbox(dict(alpha=0.5))
```

Полный список параметров, которые можно задать в этом методе, перечислен в описании конструктора для типа [`FancyBboxPatch`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.FancyBboxPatch.html#matplotlib.patches.FancyBboxPatch)